# How to send a signal from a button while the callback function of other button didn't return signal back to main() in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Here is a program in which there are two buttons (*Connect* and *Disconnect*). While clicking on 'connect' button, it calls 'button1_clicked_do_job()' function having while with some condition. On the other hand 'disconnect' button is used to change the condition of while. The problem is the *Disconnect* button is not working. How do I activate disconnect while 'connect' callback function didn't get returned to main()?

Here is the code:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

static int check=1;
void button2_clicked_disconnect(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data2)
{
    check=0; //Change the condition of while
}

void button1_clicked_do_job(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data1)
{
    do{
        g_print("Accept Connection\n");
        sleep(2);
    } while(check==1);

    g_print("Reject Connection\n");
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *fixed;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *button2;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 150);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Connect_N__Disconnect");

    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Connect");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button1, 80, 30);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button1, 30, 50);

    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Disconnect");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button2, 80, 30);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button2, 130, 50);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button1), "clicked",
                      G_CALLBACK(button1_clicked_do_job),   NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button2), "clicked",
                     G_CALLBACK(button2_clicked_disconnect), NULL);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                             G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is related to my project, please help me anyone, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you should not run blocking code (like a long running while-loop) in the main thread because it makes the app unresponsive -- all functions should preferably return in milliseconds. In your case you also expect the main loop to call your other event handler but never give the main loop a chance to do it: the while loop just keeps executing forever. In other words: the first handler needs to return before the main loop can call the second one.

How to fix that depends on what your actual problem is: Using asynchronous code or idle handlers should be the first option, and a worker thread is another (but please only add threads when you know that you actually need them). It's also possible to "pump" the event loop manually but that should really be the last option. See [main loop reference](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) for details.

Your example would look something like this:

```
gboolean check_connection (gpointer user_data)
{
    /* g_print what you want based on check value */

    if (check == 0)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

void button1_clicked_do_job(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data1)
{
     g_timeout_add_seconds (2, check_connection, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I want to handle the condition using button, but g_timeout_add_seconds() having some fixed amount of time which would control by program, but i want to handle the condition by user interaction, could it possible using threading?, like one thread in the "button1_clicked_do_job()" and another thread will change the condition using button.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking. I already said threads can be used, but advised against doing that unless you don't have other options: it's really easy to get threading wrong and usually it's not needed.

Comment: Actually, i'm working on networking project in which server side program having two button connect and disconnect. when we click on "connect" button, it will wait for connection from client side program in while loop. when user want to stop waiting for client then that time he will click "disconnect" button to change the condition in while loop.

Comment: Again, a while-loop is not the easiest solution even if it looks like one (because you then need threads). The best implementation will depend on the API that you actually use to implement the server (libsoup, GSocketService, plain sockets, something else...): regardless of the implementation, I'm almost certain you can do it without threads. E.g. in libsoup you have an asynchronous API you can use. Same with GSocketService. With plain sockets you should be able to do non-blocking IO with GLib idle handlers.